# Passing JSON String array to CXF Rest Method

Tags: json, cxf, cxfrs

I need to pass a list of strings / array of strings to a restful service method implemented using Apache CXF. I could achieve this by wrapping the ArrayList in a pojo class decorated with JAXB annotations.

Should I create a binding class just for one instance variable? My method takes only one parameter (i.e. array of strings). Can't I bind JSON array directly to an array or arraylist, instead of binding in another class?

Request JSON:

```
    {"ids":[178,304,272]}
```

POJO class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "CommonRequest")
public class WSRestCommonRequest {

private List<String> ids;
    //getter setter methods
}
```

working Method

```
@POST
@Path("cancelThese")
public void cancelThese(CommonRequest request) throws WebServiceFault {
    //---- implementation
}
```

What I am looking for

```
public void cancelThese(List<String> ids) throws WebServiceFault {
        //---- implementation
}
```

It is throwing below error

```
Headers: {exception=[Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perfectly use your method if you pass directly the JSON array `[178,304,272]`

```
@POST
@Path("cancelThese")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void cancelThese(List<String> ids) throws WebServiceFault {
        //---- implementation
}
```

Tested with CXF 3.1.6 and Jackson 2.4.2

Comment: This is not working for me. Modified question with exception details

Comment: Please include the full trace at server side and the configuration of the JSON provider (I assumed you use jackson)